# How do you see the specialization of a hired hero?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

After you hire a new hero in the Hall of Heroes, how do you see the details of his/her specialization?

When I go into the heroes heroic abilities, I can see the name of the specialization but no description. Is that a bug, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the specialization of *all* heroes is bugged when you attempt to view it from the hero's stat page.

Fortunately enough, for those heroes you hire from the Hall of Heroes, you can simply right-click their specialization to see what it is before you hire them. On the Hall of Heroes page, it should be towards the bottom of the right-side window. I'll add a pic when I can.